# Is it better to generate "UUID" and "TIMESTAMP" within the NodeJS application or the database?

Tags: node.js, typescript, database, timestamp, uuid

I am writing a TypeScript-NodeJS application and want to handle object `id`s and created_at `TIMESTAMP` within the NodeJS application, instead of using MySQL or Cassandra built-in `UUID` or `TIMESTAMP` generator.

1- First of all I like to know is this a good idea to generate `id` and `created_at` values within a web server application instead of letting databases generate them?

2- Secondly, I want to know is there a commonly used library for generating those values(`UUID` and `TIMESTAMP`) inside a NodeJS app or I should write my own functions?

3- I am also wondering know any considerations about this topic like using what version of `UUID`, etc? (All I need is generating a UNIQUE( maybe secure if needed?) `id` for each object I put into MySQL/Cassandra database, also a general `TIMESTAMP` that I can also use/generate within my `Flutter` front-end application that uses [DateTime](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html)` class)

4- Furthermore, I like to know is it a good idea to generate a `UUID` version1 that consists of `TIMESTAMP`, then extract the first part as `id` and the TIMESTAMP`part as`created_at`?